# My Muzzel Flash keeps playing even though I do not press Left Click: Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am writing a script for Raycast Shooting. I am using VSC and Unity. I was testing the script and the Muzzel Flash just kept playing and the Debug log just kept Identifying the objects it was "Shooting" at but I wasn't even clicking left click. Also, the Muzzle Flash never stopped even after I Clicked Left Click. Can Someone Help? Here is my Script:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Gun_Shooting_Script : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float damage = 10f;
    public float range = 100f;

    public Camera camera;
    public ParticleSystem muzzelFlash;


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
        
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0)); 
        {
            Shoot();
        }

        void Shoot() {

            muzzelFlash.Play();
            
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(camera.transform.position, camera.transform.forward, out hit,range));
            Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);
        }
    }          
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In update it will repeat the shoot() method, so

You should use Input.GetMouseButtonDown for the click.
I think this could help you.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Gun_Shooting_Script : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float damage = 10f;
    public float range = 100f;

    public Camera camera;
    public ParticleSystem muzzelFlash;


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() 
    {
        
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
        {
            Shoot();
        }
        else if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) 
        {
            muzzelFlash.Pause() ;
        }
    }

    void Shoot()
    {
        muzzelFlash.Play();
            
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(camera.transform.position, camera.transform.forward, out hit,range));
            Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);
    }          
}
```

Comment: No, [Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/KeyCode.Mouse0.html) is fine. It is an equivalent alternative.

Comment: What is true here though is that OP never stopped the Particles .. as said here you have to tell the particles to stop once the key is released

Comment: True had misspoke. Meant to say that using `GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0)` is the exact alternate. More getting at `KeyCode.Mouse0` is acceptable.

Comment: the script below kind of fixed my problem, but also not, the flash shows up, but then does not go until a couple of seconds. can you help?

Answer (score 1):

For starters you have your method nested inside the `Update` method. While this can be done, I'm not sure if this was your intention and in general to me this always looks uncanny.

---

Then you are stopping to call `Shoot`, yes, **but** you never tell the particles to actually stop the emission.

You could do this once the button is not pressed anymore.

Also note that you have a **very dangerous typo**: There is a `;` right after your `if` in

```
if (Physics.Raycast(camera.transform.position, camera.transform.forward, out hit, range));
    Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);
```

which basically translates to

```
if (Physics.Raycast(camera.transform.position, camera.transform.forward, out hit, range))
{

}

Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);
```

I hope you see why this is an issue ;)

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Gun_Shooting_Script : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float damage = 10f;
    public float range = 100f;

    public Camera camera;
    public ParticleSystem muzzelFlash;


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() 
    {   
        // if you actually want to shoot only once per click you should rather use 
        //if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))    
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0)) 
        {
            Shoot();
        }
        else 
        {
            if(muzzelFlash.isPlaying) 
            {
                muzzelFlash.Stop();
                // eventually you also want to remove any existing particles?
                //muzzelFlash.Clear();
            }
        }
    }

    void Shoot() 
    {
        if(!muzzleFlash.isPlaying) muzzelFlash.Play();
            
        if (!Physics.Raycast(camera.transform.position, camera.transform.forward, out var hit, range)) return;

        // in general avoid logging something every frame it is quite expensive
        Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);
    }          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using unity's particle system, if you are, check if looping is on and check if play on awake is on. If their both on, uncheck them both. Is they're both unticked, then check out the other answers, they might help.

I hope I helped you a bit! :D